# Google App Engine Remote API + OAuth

Tags: python, google-app-engine, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I'm using GAE remote api to access the data store of my app. The authentication to GAE is made using `remote_api_stub.ConfigureRemoteApi` with an authentication function that returns a user name and a password.

Is there a way for authenticating using an access_token, for example OAuth or OAuth 2.0?

Comment: ConfigureRemoteApi has an rtok parameter. Might that use the OAuth token? I haven't tried.

Comment: `rtok` is only for app_id lookups.
(from the `ConfigureRemoteApi` docstring)
>    rtok: The validation token to sent with app_id lookups. If None, a random token is used.

and in the code below, you can see:

`
  if not app_id:
    app_id = GetRemoteAppIdFromServer(server, path, rtok)
`

It appears to only be useful for checking if the given app_id exists on App Engine, not for actual authentication for remote_api_shell

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a solution for Google accounts configured to use 2-Step Verification.

At the moment, you are probably seeing a “BadAuthentication InvalidSecondFactor" error thrown, as you are not able to properly login from the shell.

In order to solve this, you will need an [App Password](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833) that authorizes the app to access your account resources. Follow the tutorial and use the generated password and the username of an admin of the target App Engine app as the credentials for Remote API.

UPDATE:

Additionally, you can take a look at the [remote_api_stub.py](http://googleappengine.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/python/google/appengine/ext/remote_api/remote_api_stub.py) file from the AppEngine SDK. You'll find a family of methods called _ConfigureRemoteApiWith* (note the leading underscore), such as:

- _ConfigureRemoteApiWithKeyFile
- _ConfigureRemoteApiWithComputeEngineCredential
- _ConfigureRemoteApiWithOAuthCredentials

Methods themselves are well documented, please take a look at their docstrings. They'll let you authenticate with safer methods than usual ASP provided by remote_api_stub.ConfigureRemoteApi().

Comment: Thanks, however this does not answer my question. My question is about authenticating without using a password at all, and using some oauth token instead.

Comment: @Tzach were you ever able to get OAuth 2.0 working with GAE. I'm interested in doing something similar.

Comment: @mba12 I didn't try as I my system doesn't connect directly to GAE anymore. Did you?

Comment: @Tzach I'm working through the GAE oauth tutorials now. Expect to have a working sample early next week. I'll let you know how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use OAuth2 to connect to your app with remote_api_stub/shell. This option is not provided.